# What is the origin of the idiom "pull yourself together"?

Tags: british-english

I understand that its meaning is to regain control of one's composure.  However, I cannot find any information about its origin.

Comment: I'm not sure of the origin (although "mind over matter" is first known in 70BCE) but it could be related to being "beside yourself", a phrase related to states of extreme emotion.

Comment: Just imagined this..it occurs in many languages. When struck by adversity or tragedy, when your *mind goes loose* and  tattered in different directions ... loses integrity to think, emote or even feel coherently... and when it later recovers by time and rest with consciousness intact ... then you have just pulled yourself up to normalcy.

Comment: Clearly it comes from an image of someone **not** being together/integral/composed: being decomposed into separate pieces - scattered. When & where did such a metaphor first come into being? When did it become a cliche/idiom? Who knows (or cares)? It's just plain description. This is no different from asking when "*compose yourself*" was first expressed.

Comment: The etymology is not 'clear' and I'll never understand what possesses people who comment to say "who cares" ... I cut my foot wide open while home alone yesterday and was panicked for a while looking at it and deciding what to do... About a centimeter deep and gaping wide like a small wedge cut out of a blood orange. The bleeding wasn't bad at all so I was able to stitch it up myself. Though I did have to literally "pull myself together" first.

Answer (score 1):

There is no clear origin, probably from the notion that a strong emotional stress  could separate the soul from the body. Compare also the expression "[be beside oneself](http://www.grammarphobia.com/blog/2015/03/beside-onerself.html)":

***[Pull oneself together](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/pull+oneself+together):***

> - Regain one's composure or self-control, as in After that frightening episode, it took her a while to pull herself together. (Second half of 1800s).

(AHD)

From the [Phrase Finder](http://www.phrases.org.uk/bulletin_board/41/messages/467.html):

> - This is a total guess. People used to believe that in times of emotional upheaval, stress, etc., a person's soul could separate from his body. You could be "beside yourself." That would result in the need to "pull yourself together."

Answer (score 1):

The expression goes back to at least [1884](https://books.google.com/books?id=1OEYAQAAIAAJ&pg=PA325&dq=%22pull+yourself+together%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi1wvTp_NDSAhXL7IMKHcYiDeE4FBDoAQgqMAM#v=onepage&q=%22pull%20yourself%20together%22&f=false), where Ngram finds several uses.  Eg:

> What will become of you,' I said, irritated by his flaccid grief and
>   tears whose fountains had been opened by alcohol, ' if you don't make
>   an effort to pull yourself together ? '

Since the uses appear to have suddenly begun at that date, in several different magazines, it's not unreasonable to guess that some other popular publication (or possibly some popular personality) originated the expression at around that time, and it was quickly picked up.  But it's an obvious enough expression that nailing it down to a specific individual or publication is likely impossible.

(However, I do note that Charles Dickens is listed as the editor of one un-attributed use, and Clement Scott and Percy White are two other authors involved.  One of them may be the source.)

As to the basis of its meaning, its sudden appearance in multiple instances in popular literature suggests the obvious:  That it is a reasonably straight-forward metaphor that requires no "back story" to understand.

Comment: There's an [earlier 1878 example](https://www.google.pt/search?num=50&espv=2&biw=1366&bih=662&tbm=bks&q=%22Come+now%2C+Macleod%2C+pull+yourself+together%22&oq=%22Come+now%2C+Macleod%2C+pull+yourself+together%22&gs_l=serp.3...5630.8416.0.8696.2.2.0.0.0.0.73.145.2.2.0....0...1c.1.64.serp..0.0.0.0OqmD-Fo-gM). (1884 was the earliest I found too when I just followed the link on the ngram page.)